# it only in insert the last matrix in the linkedlist

Tags: java, matrix, linked-list, addition

I wanna insert in a LinkedList many matrices full of many objects such as `Empty` and `Other` but it only insert the last matrix, please help

```
public LinkedList<Object[][]> addMatrices()
{
    LinkedList<Object[][]> l=new LinkedList<>();
    Object[][] o=new Object[2][2];
    o[0][0]=new Empty(2);
    o[0][1]=new Other();    
    o[1][0]=new Empty(4);
    o[1][1]=new Empty(6);
    l.add(o);
    o[0][0]=new Empty(4);
    o[0][1]=new Other();    
    o[1][0]=new Empty(5);
    o[1][1]=new Empty(1);
    l.add(o);
    for(Object[][] oo:l)
    {

        for(int x=0;x<oo.length;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<oo[x].length;y++)
                {System.out.print("\t"+oo[x][y]+" ");
            System.out.print("\t|");}
            System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
    }
    return l;
}
```

output:

```
4   |   -1  |

5   |   1   |


4   |   -1  |

5   |   1   |
```

it suppose to be like that :

```
2   |   -1  |

4   |   6   |


4   |   -1  |

5   |   1   |
```

Comment: Not clear that what the class `Empty` and class `Other` refers to. Need to share a clear understandable way or try to reframe your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your Object o is added by reference to the LinkedList l. So you actually override the first added object and it looks as if only the last gets added.

Try it this way:

```
public LinkedList<Object[][]> addMatrices()
{
    LinkedList<Object[][]> l=new LinkedList<>();
    Object[][] o=new Object[2][2];
    o[0][0]=new Empty(2);
    o[0][1]=new Other();    
    o[1][0]=new Empty(4);
    o[1][1]=new Empty(6);
    l.add(o);

    Object[][] o2=new Object[2][2];
    o2[0][0]=new Empty(4);
    o2[0][1]=new Other();    
    o2[1][0]=new Empty(5);
    o2[1][1]=new Empty(1);
    l.add(o2);

    for(Object[][] oo:l)
    {

       for(int x=0;x<oo.length;x++){
           for(int y=0;y<oo[x].length;y++) {
               System.out.print("\t"+oo[x][y]+" ");
               System.out.print("\t|");}
               System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
           }
           System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());
       }
    return l;
}
```